# Uncaught ReferenceError: X is not defined - declaring object on js file, making reference inside html button event

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I want to define a Javascript object inside a js file and make it possible for users to create new instances of it on their HTML by calling the src on the head and then using "new". [maybe this is not the best approach, but bear with me] -- very basic stuff, right?

Code in JS file myFile.js:

```
function myObject(){
   this.myMethod = thisMethod;

   function thisMethod(){
     return 2;
   }
}
```

Code in HTML:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://myserver/myFile.js">
     var customObject = new myObject();     
  </script>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="alert(customObject.myMethod());">
</body>
```

However, when you click the button, you get an error:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: customObject is not defined"

I am sure this is about how I am declaring the instance and then calling it. If I put the var declaration inside the js file, the click works:

```
    function myObject(){
       this.myMethod = thisMethod;

       function thisMethod(){
         return 2;
       }
    }

var customObject = new myObject();
```

But this defeats the purpose of letting the user create the object and use it at will.

Of course there is a problem with my structure, but all my researches don't give me a clue. I thought bringing the js file was the same as putting the code inside script tag in the HEAD and instantiating the object there -- because if I do that, without .js call, it works.

I have many theories, some of them regarding events and the order where things are loaded, but don't want to clutter this question.

**So the question is: how to you define an object in a js file, then let the user instantiate and call its methods inside the HTML? (Especially for events like onclick)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use the same  tag to both include an external resource and define your javascript code. You have to use 2 separate tags, otherwise whatever code you put inside the tags will be omitted. This works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myserver/myFile.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    var customObject = new myObject();     
</script>
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: THANKS! That was exactly the problem. I was overthinking and missing the basics.

Comment: Great! Please mark the post as answered so you can help others.